# Building Boost Libraries With Intel Compiler

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-construction, build, icc

I have installed Intel Parallel Studio XE 2013 in addition to Visual Studio 2012 on a 32bit Windows 7 machine. I have tried to build Boost 1.53 with Intel compiler by following the instructions in the [link](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/building-boost-with-intel-c-composer-xe-2013-on-windows-7). I have this error:

> .\boost/config/select_stdlib_config.hpp(18): catastrophic error:
>   cannot open source file "cstddef"

Is there anyone else who had the same problem? I would welcome any advice to link standard libraries of ICC to boost build process.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After an intensive search, finally I have found the solution. As explained in this [link](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/BOOST-BUILD-Building-Boost-with-Intel-Composer-XE-v12-Windows-issues-td4015638.html), there are two patches to apply to boost folder:

1. `intel-win.jam` file in [boost-source-directory]\tools\build\v2\tools needs to be replaced by the file given in the [link](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/attachment/4021389/0/intel-win.jam).
2. `project-config.jam` needs to be replaced by `intel-user-config.jam` given in the [link](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/attachment/4021389/1/intel-user-config.jam) and build command should be changed to:

> b2 --user-config=intel-user-config.jam --toolset=intel

Note that intel compiler version number may need to be modified according to your existing ICC installation in the file `intel-user-config.jam`.

Comment: Good work. Thanks for sharing this. Future SO users will be grateful. And therefore, me, now :)

Answer (score 2):

Run "./bootstrap.sh --with-toolset=intel-linux" and "b2 install" will use intel-linux.compile.c++ (boost_1_64_0).

Comment: Your suggestion is for Linux. The OP has asked for Windows: "I have installed Intel Parallel Studio XE 2013 in addition to Visual Studio 2012 on a 32bit Windows 7 machine. ".

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer to the topic in [this link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/746371) solved a similar problem for me, which pertained to Intel Compiler 17.0 Update 5 and Visual Studio 17.

You need to change a couple of lines in  tools/build/src/tools/intel-win.jam

Note, the build proceeds with a number of warnings.