# Building boost with Intel C++ Composer XE 2013

Tags: c++, boost, build, icc

I have installed Intel C++ Composer XE 2013, and I'm trying to build boost (1_61_0) with it (on windows 8). 
I followed the steps on the official website [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/building-boost-with-intel-c-composer-xe-2013-on-windows-7) and modified the files as suggested on the related topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22351863/building-boost-libraries-with-intel-compiler) (also modifying 12.0 to 13.0 in the intel-user-config.jam, and going to src instead of v2 folder). 
The command b2 --user-config=intel-user-config.jam --toolset=intel seemed to work properly.

However, my build.bat still does not work (so probably I did not build it properly):

```
@echo off  
set currentdir=%cd%  
@call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Composer XE 2013\bin\iclvars.bat" ia32  
icl /fast HelloWorld.cpp  
pause
```

The error message being related to boost:

> catastrophic error: cannot open source file "boost/math/distributions/normal.hpp"

Do I need to do something else in my .cpp file in order to use boost? Or did I just not installed it properly? Maybe it's my version of boost?
I'm very new to C++, compilers, etc. I have been trying to figure something out to make boost work for days and I am still unable to use it. I have tried what was suggested on other topics but without success. I don't even know where the problem is.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's simply that the compiler doesn't know the location of the `boost` include files. You can usually add it as a command line parameter. Try`icl /help` to discover precisely how.

Comment: icl /I "C:\boost_1_61_0" /fast HelloWorld.cpp
solves the problem. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
icl /I "C:\boost_1_61_0" /fast HelloWorld.cpp
```

solves the problem. Thanks